# Altering a control based on a variable name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I got a series of comboboxes that have items that are retrieved from a query. Depending on what the user selects the correct combobox needs to be filled (or updated). So if the user selects "Fish" then "ComboBox_Fish" would need to be changed.

But how can i accomplish this? For testing purposes i tried to change the Text with the following code:

```
((ComboBox)Controls["ComboBox_" + Name ]).Text = "Test";
```

but it gives me this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

Info that might be relevant: 
All ComboBoxes are located in the same TableLayoutPanal which is in a TabPage of a TabControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Info that might be relevant: All ComboBoxes are located in the same TableLayoutPanal which is in a TabPage of a TabControl.

Then you need to access the `Controls` property of the panel in question

```
((ComboBox)this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls["ComboBox_" + Name ]).Text = "Test";
```

Comment: Actually only forgot it here, not in the code. My apologies.

Comment: @A.bakker ok removed that point and added the response to your extra relevant info

Comment: I almost wanted to say that i already tried that 2, but then i noticed the "this". forgot that in my own attempts. will mark as answered as soon as i am able to.

Comment: A bit of a follow up question, how would this control be reached when it is located in a different class?

Comment: @A.bakker you would need to make the control public. How did you create it? in the designer via drag and drop? or did you instantiate it in the code?

Comment: @A.bakker "how would this control be reached" what exactly is meant by **this control** ? the `tableLayoutPanel1` ? or the combobox ?

Comment: The Combobox. So basically this code but then placed in a different class then the main form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204540/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-a-bakker).